# RODBC lose connection after running randomForestSRC

Tags: r, random-forest, rodbc

I open an connection to Vertica through RODBC, then I run a rfsrc function from randomForestSRC package, then the connection get lost. The even wired thing is that when running rfsrc function for some dataset, the connection was kept and for some others the connection get lost.

Here is code: (I use the latest randomForestSRC and RODBC package)

```
library(parallel)
library(randomForestSRC)
library(RODBC)

data(veteran, package = "randomForestSRC")
data(breast, package = "randomForestSRC")
data(pbc, package = "randomForestSRC")
data(wihs, package = "randomForestSRC")
data(follic, package = "randomForestSRC")

db_str <- "**********************"
bi_con <- odbcDriverConnect(db_str, believeNRows=FALSE,rows_at_time=100000)
sql <- "insert into testing123 values('abcd');"
result <- sqlQuery(bi_con, sql)
print(result)
cat("\r\n")

#obj1 <- rfsrc(status ~ ., data = breast, nsplit=10) # lose connection
#obj2 <- rfsrc(Surv(time, status)~., data = veteran, nsplit = 10, ntree = 100) # works
#obj3 <- rfsrc(Surv(days,status) ~ ., pbc, nsplit = 10) # works
#obj4 <- rfsrc(Surv(time, status) ~ ., wihs, nsplit = 3, ntree = 100) # works
#obj5 <- rfsrc(Ozone ~ ., data = airquality) # works
obj6 <- rfsrc(Species ~., data = iris) # lose connection
#obj7 <- rfsrc(Surv(time, status) ~ ., follic, nsplit = 3, ntree = 100) # lose connection

sql <- "insert into testing123 values('abcde')"
result <- sqlQuery(bi_con, sql)
print(result)
odbcClose(bi_con)
```

For now, I think it is because the Garbage Collection of R remove and close the db connection. Could anyone help on this? thanks.

Here is the error message:

```
[1] "HY000 10 [Vertica][VerticaDSII] (10) An error occurred during query preparation: no connection to the server\n"
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'insert into testing123 values('abcde')'"
```

Here is the **minimum version** of the script which I run on my own machine:

```
library(randomForestSRC)
library(RODBC)

db_str <- "********************************"
bi_con <- odbcDriverConnect(db_str, believeNRows=FALSE,rows_at_time=1)
sql <- "insert into testing123 values('abcd');"

result <- sqlQuery(bi_con, sql)
print(result)
cat("\r\n")

obj <- rfsrc(Species ~., data = iris) # lose connection

sql <- "insert into testing123 values('abcdef')"
result <- sqlQuery(bi_con, sql)
print(result) # this line will produce the error message above
```

***After observing the dataset, disfference between conn-breaking and conn-non-breaking datasets is that all dataset that break the rodbc connection contain a non-numberic column(string column), and all dataset that keep the rodbc connection contain only numberic column.***

**Finaly I use RJDBC and it works well with randomForestSRC package**

Comment: unless the actual scoping isn't as in your example, there isn't any reason I see for garbage collection to come into play.  Do your rfsrc calls take a really long time?  I work with RODBC and sql server daily, and connections do typically timeout after some length

Comment: although timeout doesn't explain why in your commented code the first call fails yet the second call runs?  Is that accurate because I feel like it isn't

Comment: @DMT thanks for reply. This script is complete one which I use to run. The obj1 to obj7 examples work on small dataset and run within 10 seconds for each one. The obj1 will cause this line fail result <- sqlQuery(bi_con, sql) and obj2 will not.

Comment: so just to be perfectly clear.  If you include the calls to set obj1, obj6, or obj7, then the dbConnection is lost.  Yet if you only include the calls obj2-obj6, the dbConnection remains open?

Comment: @DMT No. each one has independent affect on the connection, which mean if any of obj1, obj6, obj7 included in the run, the connection will break.

Comment: There is no apparent reason to me why this should happen, and it's a bit hard to test on my side because of the dbConnection.  But there may be a way around this.  Is it necessary to define the db connection prior to the rfsrc calls?  Obviously you've targeted those as the problem, so you can take them out of the equation by defining your db connection as late as possible

Comment: @DMT The real code will create a local temp table for the later usage, but when this connection get lost, the local temp table gone. It is not my code though, it is worth asking about bypassing the rfsrc function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding there isn't any reason why R garbage collection would target your db connection, unless the scoping you presented isn't indicative of what you're actually running.  It might be some nuanced aspect of the rfsrc calls that effect the environment, but I'm not familiar with that package.  It is also pretty much impossible for me personally to reproduce your problem.

There are two possibilities from my point of view.  Take the rfsrc calls out of the equation and define your database connection after them. If that is not a possibility you can do the following as a hack.  You would place this function call after all the rfsrc calls.

```
connectionTest<-function(dbConn){
    newDbConn<-dbConn
    tryCatch(
        result<-odbcGetInfo(dbConn),

        #redefine the db connection if it isn't active
        error=function(e){newDbConn<-bi_con <- odbcDriverConnect(db_str, believeNRows=FALSE,rows_at_time=100000)}
    )
    newDbConn
}
```

Then you would call

```
  bi_con<-connectionTest(bi_con)
```

before your second query.

Like I said, pure hack, but I can't reproduce your problem and don't know enough about the the randomForestSRC package to give a better answer (if there is one)

Comment: The strange thing is that if I call result<-odbcGetInfo(dbConn), print(result) before and after rfsrc function, they will produce the exact same result(not using your function but print dbinfo directly), but the query after the rfsrc function will fail, not sure if this gives more information. Thanks .

Comment: That does actually, odbcGetInfo will throw an error if the connection is lost (hence why I tryCatched).  If odbcGetInfo(bi_con) after all the rfsrc calls does not throw an error, it seems to imply that the connection is still open, at least from the R side, but maybe not from the server side.  Why are you setting believeNRows to FALSE?  I'd give the call a shot with simply the connection information (db_str) and let everything else go to default

Comment: I use odbcDriverConnect(db_str) now, but it creates the same error. I am not sure if it the R side or the server side, since some dataset may keep the connection some of them may break it. This is the part I couldn't understand. All of the datasets are small(a few hundred rows)

Comment: Have you tried making calls to the db in sequence?  For example, make two calls in a row to the db.  The rfsrc calls aren't utilizing the database at all, so my feeling is that those calls aren't "breaking" the connection, but that possibly the server doesn't allow more than one call per the connection you set up.  If you can query the db two separate times in a row, then that would refute what I just said.  If you can't make two calls in a row, then it might be time to look at db_str

Comment: Yes, I did, I could make multiple calls simply comment out the rfsrc function. I add some more information in the end of the post, I think there is something happen within the rfsrc function...

Comment: unless bi_con is randomly a variable used in rfsrc, the dbconnection isn't used in rfsrc.  As a last ditch effort you could change the name of your db connection to something else (like dbConn), otherwise I've got nothing.  Only thing I could suggest is move the db connection initialization to somewhere after the rfsrc calls

Comment: Thanks @DMT, I finally use the RJDBC which works well with randomForestSRC package